# Javascript: array ask the current day from the week

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am brand new with javascript and I am struggling a lot. I am doing school work to learn javascript. My first end task is how to ask current day of the week. I will explain.

Request the day of the week via JavaScript. So the computer date, not through a prompt.

Create an array: dayNames. This already contains the names of the days.

Write the name of the day in the document via JS.
If it is a weekday, also write:
It's a workday, so get to work.
If it is a weekend day, write:
It's the weekend, break.

So the result is eg.
Today is “Thursday”.
It's a workday, so get to work.

```js
        let daynames =  ["maandag", "dinsdag", "woensdag", "donderdag","vrijdag", "zaterdag", "zondag"];

        if(daynames == daynames.getDay()){
            print ("It's a workday")
        }

        else(daynames == daynames.getDay()) {
            print("It's weekendday")
        }

        document.write(`<p>Today is ${daynames}</p>`);
```

the only thing I am strunggling with is ask the current day throu an array that has the weekdays and weekend. I know it's probally with an IF and ELSE but I got no idea how.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and adapt your question accordingly ...

Comment: I know and you are right, I have done everything first and try by myself so far I have finished 85% of my homework, this is the only last task i can't find the answer for. Otherwise i won't be asking help here if I could solve it. I've spend and did everything for like 3 days now. I just want to know what i am doing wrong.

i created the array, tried IF and ELSE to see how i can get the current day but nothing so far.

Comment: You don't get the point: If you don't show, what you have done already, nobody is able to help you ...

Comment: ok, I'll edit it and show it hang on

Answer (score 0):

To get the current day, you should use

```
Date.prototype.getDay()
```

This method will return An integer number, between 0 and 6, corresponding to the day of the week for the given date, according to local time: 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, and so on.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

Because the method returns 0 for Sunday, it is easier to put Sunday as the first item in the array.

```
let daynames =  ["zondag", "maandag", "dinsdag", "woensdag", "donderdag","vrijdag", "zaterdag"];

const today = new Date().getDay()

//prepare the string to output
let output = ""

// if today is 0 meaning Sunday or 6 meaning Saturday, it is the weekend
//else it is a weekday
if(today === 0 || today === 6){
  output = `Today is ${daynames[today]}, it is the weekend.`
}
else{
  output = `Today is ${daynames[today]}, it is a weekday.`
}

document.write(output)
```

Comment: This `today === daynames.length -1` condition is a bit dangerous, as it depends on the `daynames` array to be initialized correctly ... Better would be `if (today === 0 || today === 6)` or even simpler `if (today % 6 === 0)`